# How to After pulling info from DB send an email

Tags: php

This is working just fine on a single page. It gives me all information I need. But I want to send an email with it. Although I couldn`t figure out how can I do it

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'panel');
$sql = "select * from detail";
$read = $db->query($sql);

<table style="border:0;width:600px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="50px">Who</td>
    <td width="150px">Time</td>
    <td width="300px">What</td>
  </tr>
<?php 
while($wr = mysqli_fetch_array($read)) {
 echo' <tr>
    <td>'.$wr['Who'].'</td>
    <td>'.$wr['Time'].'</td>
    <td>'.$wr['What'].'</td>
  </tr> ';
}


?>
```

Comment: What is the data you are trying to send ?

Comment: Try looking at the [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buffer all of the HTML you're generating (which means not sending it to the browser but to accumulate it in a buffer) and send that buffer to the user as email like this:

```
// Start buffering
ob_start();
// Generate HTML just like you're doing now
echo( "<html><body><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></body></html>" );
// Get the contents of the buffer
$html = ob_get_contents();
// Stop the buffering
ob_end_clean();

// Now use the content string you have to send an email just like the example at:
// http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: to@domain.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: from@domain.com' . "\r\n";

mail( "to@domain.com", "This is the subject", $html, $headers );
```

Comment: I couldn`t really understand what do I need to do but I`ll give a shot

Comment: Well, if i understood you correctly, you wish to send the generated HTML as an email and in that case, what my script does is let you "send" HTML the same way you usually do but instead of sending it over the network to the browser, the HTML is accumulated in a buffer (which is handled by PHP) and can be later on collected using `ob_get_contents()`.  The end result is a string comprised of the HTML which was supposed to be sent to the browser.