# How to get a HTML table as a PHP variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using DOMpdf to create pdf files. To print the following table I have to get it as a variable and then send it to my controller. just like `$value = "Some value(in this place I want the following table) ";` But here in this case I am not sure how get this entire table inside a variable when you have some PHP script to populate data.

Please help.

```
   <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <h1> Batch Name: <?php echo "$batchname";?> </h1>
            <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.N</th>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Exam Date</th>
                        <th>Exam Type</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Total Mark</th>
                        <th>Highest Mark</th>
                        <th>Obtained Mark</th>
                        <th>GPA</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Status</th>

                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>


                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>

                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>viewbatch/get/<?php echo $row['studentid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['studentid'];?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examdate'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examtype'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['highestmark'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['obtainedmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['gradepoint'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['grade'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>



                    </tr>
            <?php  } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Check out my response at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657831/how-to-after-pulling-info-from-db-send-an-email/8657946#8657946, you have to tell PHP to buffer the data instead of sending it to the browser, draw the HTML normally and then ask the buffered content back from PHP as a string, at which point you will have a string containing the HTML which you just drew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
ob_start(); 
if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <h1> Batch Name: <?php echo "$batchname";?> </h1>
            <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.N</th>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Exam Date</th>
                        <th>Exam Type</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Total Mark</th>
                        <th>Highest Mark</th>
                        <th>Obtained Mark</th>
                        <th>GPA</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Status</th>

                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>


                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>

                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>viewbatch/get/<?php echo $row['studentid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['studentid'];?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examdate'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examtype'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['highestmark'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['obtainedmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['gradepoint'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['grade'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>



                    </tr>
            <?php  } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
<?php
$output = ob_get_clean();
 ?>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe heredoc syndax would help:

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html